# Safari bug. When trying to animate svg a transformation with a blur filter, safari is very laggy

Tags: javascript, svg, optimization, safari, gsap

I spent a lot of time looking for a similar problem and couldn't find anything. Please help solve this gap on safari.

I am trying to animate pictures in svg, with a blur filter. This works great in all browsers except safari. I prepared a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7pne23Lk/11/

I would be glad for any help or ideas! Thank you

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 250 250">
    <defs>
        <mask id="circleClip" clipPathUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="80" fill="#fff"></circle>
        </mask>
        
        <circle id="circleA" cx="100" cy="100" r="80"></circle>
        <circle id="circleC" cx="100" cy="100" r="80"></circle>

        <filter id="circleB" width="123%" height="123%" x="-11.5%" y="-11.5%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox">
            <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" result="shadowBlurInner1" stdDeviation="4"></feGaussianBlur>
            <feOffset dy="8" in="shadowBlurInner1" result="shadowOffsetInner1"></feOffset>
            <feComposite in="shadowOffsetInner1" in2="SourceAlpha" k2="-1" k3="1" operator="arithmetic" result="shadowInnerInner1"></feComposite>
            <feColorMatrix in="shadowInnerInner1" result="shadowMatrixInner1" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.2 0"></feColorMatrix>
            <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" result="shadowBlurInner2" stdDeviation="4"></feGaussianBlur>
            <feOffset dy="-8" in="shadowBlurInner2" result="shadowOffsetInner2"></feOffset>
            <feComposite in="shadowOffsetInner2" in2="SourceAlpha" k2="-1" k3="1" operator="arithmetic" result="shadowInnerInner2"></feComposite>
            <feColorMatrix in="shadowInnerInner2" result="shadowMatrixInner2" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.2 0"></feColorMatrix>
            <feMerge>
                <feMergeNode in="shadowMatrixInner1"></feMergeNode>
                <feMergeNode in="shadowMatrixInner2"></feMergeNode>
            </feMerge>
        </filter>
        <filter id="motionBlur" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"><feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="0,0"></feGaussianBlur></filter>
    </defs>
    
        <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
            <use fill="#222731" xlink:href="#circleA"></use>
            <g stroke-linejoin="round">
                <use fill="#000" filter="url(#circleB)" xlink:href="#circleC"></use>
                <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="86" stroke="#272d39" stroke-width="10.764"></circle>
            </g>
        </g>
        
     
<g transform="translate(0,0)" mask="url(#circleClip)">
            <g class="items" transform="translate(36, 36)" filter="url(#motionBlur)">
                <image width="128px" height="128px" xlink:href="https://i.imgur.com/xSpsoPm.png"></image>
                <image width="128px" height="128px" y="-128" xlink:href="https://i.imgur.com/JuG5GrL.png"></image>
                <image width="128px" height="128px" y="-256" xlink:href="https://i.imgur.com/BB2GgC6.png"></image>
                <image width="128px" height="128px" y="-384" xlink:href="https://i.imgur.com/xSpsoPm.png"></image>
                <image width="128px" height="128px" y="-512" xlink:href="https://i.imgur.com/JuG5GrL.png"></image>
                <image width="128px" height="128px" y="-640" xlink:href="https://i.imgur.com/BB2GgC6.png"></image>
                <image width="128px" height="128px" y="-768" xlink:href="https://i.imgur.com/xSpsoPm.png"></image>
                <image width="128px" height="128px" y="-896" xlink:href="https://i.imgur.com/JuG5GrL.png"></image>
                <image width="128px" height="128px" y="-1024" xlink:href="https://i.imgur.com/BB2GgC6.png"></image>
                <image width="128px" height="128px" y="-1152" xlink:href="https://i.imgur.com/xSpsoPm.png"></image>
                <image width="128px" height="128px" y="-1280" xlink:href="https://i.imgur.com/JuG5GrL.png"></image>
                <image width="128px" height="128px" y="-1408" xlink:href="https://i.imgur.com/BB2GgC6.png"></image>
                <image width="128px" height="128px" y="-1536" xlink:href="https://i.imgur.com/xSpsoPm.png"></image>
                <image width="128px" height="128px" y="-1664" xlink:href="https://i.imgur.com/JuG5GrL.png"></image>
                <image width="128px" height="128px" y="-1792" xlink:href="https://i.imgur.com/BB2GgC6.png"></image>           
            </g>
        </g>
   
</svg>

<button id="play">
  play
</button>
```

```
const blur = document.querySelector("#motionBlur");
const blurFilter = blur.firstElementChild;
const items = document.querySelector('.items');
const button = document.querySelector('#play');


function animate() {
  gsap.set(items, { y: 140 });

  const tl = gsap.timeline();

  tl.to(items, {duration: 0.5, y: 1195, onUpdate: () => {
    const progress = tl.progress() * 20;
    blurFilter.setAttribute('stdDeviation', `0,${20 - progress}`);

    if (tl.progress() >= 0.9) {
      blurFilter.setAttribute('stdDeviation', `0,0`);
    }

  }})
}

button.addEventListener("click", animate, false);
```

Answer (score 2):

SVG filter animation performance in Safari can be poor - so that's not completely unexpected. I have a couple of suggestions.

1. Add color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" to your svg element
2. Magical suggestion - break your SVG up into two separate SVG elements - with the non-animated filter and content in one of them and the animated filter and content in the other. I don't know if this will work, but it's worth trying. Your first filter is quite complicated, and if Safari is re-rendering it on every tick of your animation (even though it's not animated) - it could be killing your performance.
3. Another approach would be to use the "use" element to pre-render 20 copies of your images drawn on top of each other with different blur levels and then use opacity animations to progressively disclose & hide each layer. Opacity animations are usually fast - even on Safari, so this might be a hack that works although it makes your markup more complex. (Also another tip - don't animate the opacity from 0 to 1 - animate from 0.01 or 0.04 to 1 - webkit sometimes optimizes by not rendering 0 opacity content - and in this case you're trying to force it to do that.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I noticed a change in performance even without a filter, specifically on the transformation animation - it also lags in safari